# Can I apply for Postdoctoral Research Assistant as a fresh MSc graduate?

Tags: masters, postdocs

I know it sounds stupid but I have applied for a Postdoctoral Research Assistant at a university in London and I have received an invitation for a Skype interview. However, I am a fresh MSc graduate having finished my masters two months ago. One of the job requirements says "PhD and/or equivalent professional experience" as essential skill, yet they invited me for a Skype interview.

Now I am wondering if this was a mistake or am I just shortlisted??

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe they missed, somehow, that you don't have a doctorate. Maybe they think you are on the cusp of earning it. Many people apply just before finishing a PhD. Maybe you should clarify with them. Or maybe, not likely, they have very flexible rules about it.

Comment: Technically, a PhD in the UK _isn't_ necessary (I know or have seen several _Lecturers_ without a PhD), but you have to demonstrate equivalent skill and expertise. My guess is, nobody expects a fresh MSc graduate to apply for post-_doctoral_ positions, they missed it and invited you by mistake not realising you're nowhere near PhD completion, sorry :(

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yeah, I was thinking there must be a mistake because my CV says I have finished MSc in September 2019. I wanted to check with people here before I ask them. Thanks for the response once again.

Comment: Many options, either they missed the fact that you don't have a PhD, or they are actually considering you as a PostDoc, or they are interested in you as a PhD student and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I expect this is a mistake on the university's part. Many people apply for postdocs in the final year of their PhD, so perhaps they misinterpreted your CV and thought you were in that category.

There is likely to be a requirement in the formal job description that candidates must have, or be near to completing a PhD, so even if you were to attend and do well at the interview, I highly doubt they would be able to make you a job offer anyway.

My advice is to send them an email thanking them for the invitation to interview but clearly state that you do not have a PhD nor are you a current PhD student. It is likely they will rescind the interview offer.

Answer (score 0):

PostDoc stands for post doctorate so typically that means you've already obtained a PhD. Then again, it's not fixed in stone if the applicant is deemed to be of such a high caliber that they would consider that person to be eligible for that position. But this is very *rare*.